# bmake stuck and not progress (upon building pkg-config)

Tags: pkg-config, qnx, qnx-neutrino

Upon building a component (`pkg-config`) under `pkgsrc` directory, I get stuck being told `checking for a compliant posix_memalign() implementation...` as in the trace below. CPU remains 99% and doesn't seem to progress for a few hours. Any ideas what could be wrong is appreciated.

To install pkgsrc, I followed [Bootstrap instruction here](http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.pkgsrc/wiki/Bootstrap), using HEaD_650. Precise commands since installing pkgsrc until where I got stuck:

```
# uname -a
QNX localhost 6.5.0 2012/06/20-13:50:59EDT x86pc x86
# svn checkout --username <username> http://community.qnx.com/svn/repos/pkgsrc/HEAD_650
# cd pkgsrc/bootstrap && ./bootstrap
# cd ../devel/pkg-config
# pwd 
/usr/share/pkgsrc/devel/pkg-config
# bmake 
:
checking for fd_set... yes, found in sys/select.h
checking whether realloc (NULL,) will work... yes
checking for nl_langinfo (CODESET)... no
checking for nl_langinfo (PM_STR)... no
checking for nl_langinfo (_NL_CTYPE_OUTDIGITn_MB)... no
checking for a compliant posix_memalign() implementation...
```

Using QNX6.5.0 SDP1

(By the way, I'm not sure if the way I'm doing above is the right to way to get `pkg-config` on `QNX` in general.)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out based on the workaround suggested in [this link](http://community.qnx.com/sf/discussion/do/listPosts/projects.core_os/discussion.newcode.topc22167).

I did the following:

```
# pwd
/usr/share/pkgsrc/devel/pkg-config
# export MALLOC_BAND_CONFIG_STR="8:16,32,0:24,32,0:32,32,0:48,24,0:64,24,0:80,24,0:96,16,0:128,8,0"
# bmake            (this finishes this time)
```